# Какой самой простой конструкцией в одном SQL-запросе извлечь несколько значений из одной колонки, каждое по своему условию?

Tags: mysql, sql

Вопрос возник в контексте следующей задачи:

Есть вспомогательная таблица признаков `prop`, содержащая среди прочего для каждого признака его уникальные название `prop.name(CHAR[32])` и идентификатор `prop.id(INT)`.

Есть основная таблица неких сущностей `entity`, содержащая среди прочего для каждой сущности по 3 признака: `entity.prop1(INT)`, `entity.prop2(INT)` и `entity.prop3(INT)`.

Необходимо в таблицу `entity` добавить новую сущность при помощи конструкции:

```
INSERT INTO entity(prop1,prop2,prop3) SELECT...
```

передав в качестве входных параметров не идентификаторы 3 признаков, а их названия, чтобы запрос сам вместо названий подставил соответствующие идентификаторы из вспомогательной таблицы.

При установке только 1 признака, например, первого, можно использовать такой запрос:

```
INSERT INTO entity(prop1,prop2,prop3) SELECT id,0,0 FROM prop WHERE name='Имя 1 признака'
```

Какой сформировать SQL-запрос, если надо установить сразу несколько признаков, например все 3?

Comment: Схема данных неоптимальна. Вот и приходится хитрые запросы сочинять. В ходе сочинения этого вопроса должна была появиться мысль, что таких задач быть не должно. Тут просится таблица связи prop и entity - тогда запросы будут просты и очевидны.

Comment: ну если "в лоб", то `insert ... select (select id from prop ...), (select id from prop ...), (select id from prop ...)`

Comment: А создайте лучше fiddle с примером исходных данных (или хотя бы дайте CREATE TABLE и INSERT INTO), дайте параметры для вставки и покажите требуемый результат для этих данных и параметров.